# How to properly style a text area with inner shadows and scrollbar

Tags: html, css, textarea, shadow

I'm putting an inner-shadow on all my controls, inputs and textareas by using the following CSS:

```
input {
  padding: 7px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px #dddddd;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px #dddddd;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px #dddddd;
}
```

and, with some other styling, looks like this (in Firefox, and similar in other browsers):

[image]

But the padding that helps separate the content from the inner shadow breaks the textarea around the scrollbar:

[image]

and if I remove the padding, the text overlaps the shadow, like this:

[image]

I can add padding only to the left, solving the overlap with the left shadow but not with the top shadow, while having the scrollbar look good:

[image]

I can also add padding everywhere but on the right side, having the text displayed correctly but the toolbar still looks rather odd:

[image]

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Getting the `padding` property to affect only the content but not the scrollbar is not possible using standard textarea elements. For that you can use a `contenteditable` DIV. For example, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AQjN7/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer" contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px #dddddd;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px #dddddd;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px #dddddd;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    width: 300px;    
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
​
```

Comment: I see... oh well... before doing that, I should probably decide whether plain text is ever going to be used, or whether I should go for some rich text editor anyway. Do you know what's the browser support for contenteditable? where is it going to fail?

Comment: It has pretty good support in all modern browsers including FF, Chrome as well as IE. However browsers as sick as IE7 can break anything. :)

Comment: If you want to post the textarea data with a normal html form, data in a contenteditable div won't be posted. It will be with a textarea. Still a neat idea.

Comment: You can do that by adding a hidden input field and copying the text value from the div prior to submit (i.e onsubmit returning true).

Comment: This solution worked for me on Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS X as well as IE 9, 8, 7 and even 6. I mean, trying out the look and feel, not sure if it messes up the form for example.

Comment: The trouble with contenteditable is that you can copy+paste (or select+drag) arbitrary formatted HTML into it, which is [sometimes a nice feature](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php), but not if you're trying to replace a plain textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add: `padding-right: 0;` to the textarea selector and it will line up your scrollbar with the side of the element. :)

Comment: If I do that, the top and bottom of the scrollbars are still not aligned. It looks rather odd.

Comment: Are you using a custom scrollbar there?

Comment: Nope, the standard one. That's Firefox on MacOSX. I'll post another screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the textarea in a div:

```
<div class="textarea-wrapper">
    <textarea>
</div>
```

css:

```
.textarea-wrapper{
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px #ddd;
}
textarea {
    padding: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

A jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rXpPy/

Comment: I thought of that, but that padding that would cause the text to not overlap the shadow, the padding on textarea, would also cause the the scrollbar to be separated from the borders.

Comment: Please see the jsFiddle I added to my answer.

Comment: Which browser are you using? My chrome on ubuntu ignores the padding at the scrollbar, but it does to padding for the content.

Comment: Oh nice... at least in Chrome in MacOSX looks nice.

Comment: Well, it works on Chrome in MacOSX, but not on Firefox or IE :/

Answer (score 0):

Additionally - rather than using simply input, which will target buttons, you can target text inputs specifically with

```
input[type="text"]
```